# Calling Python API - Google App Engine

Tags: java, android, python, google-app-engine

I am a little confused when it comes to using the API generated from the .JAR that was generated from using my Python API for Google App Engine.

Below there is an example of a method and an AsyncTask to create and store an Event entity in the Datastore.

**Would you typically use the Request/Response Messages to pass data to the entity?**

I have an Event class that has an insert() method but it doesn't let me pass any of the event details to it because it lacks any setters/getters like the Request/Response classes

```
private void sendResultToServer(String eventDesc, String eventName,
        String eventTime) {
    ImhotepApiMessagesEventRequest newEvent = new ImhotepApiMessagesEventRequest();
    newEvent.setEventDesc(eventDesc);
    newEvent.setEventTitle(eventName);
    newEvent.setEventTime(eventTime);
    new SendResultToServerTask().execute(newEvent, null, null);
}

/**
 * Handles the request to the Event Endpoint, to save a event, without
 * blocking the UI.
 */
private class SendResultToServerTask extends
        AsyncTask<ImhotepApiMessagesEventRequest, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(
            ImhotepApiMessagesEventRequest... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        service.event();
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: The AppEngine Java and Python APIs are separate and porting Python code will not work.  You appear to be missing some concepts.  Your example is Java so you should study [Java Datastore API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/) and [Samples](https://developers.google.com/appengine/).  To answer your question, yes, you would typically use request parameters in a doPost event handler to pass data to the entity, and submit the post from an HTML form or a jQuery Ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

The Java [Using the Datastore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/usingdatastore) example is a good starting point for creating your own Entities with the guestbook doPost handler.  After the example is up and running you could extend it towards Task Queues.

The first code example in [Using Push Queues in Java](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview-push) adds a named parameter to an asynchronous task invocation.  According to [Class TaskOptions](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/TaskOptions) you can chain .param("name","value") calls.